# User automatically redirected to main language page

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

In my website I have the users automatically redirected to the main language page.

If for example: node/2 is the translation of node/1
when I type: www.mywebsite.com/node/2 I'm immediately redirected to www.mywebsite.com/node/1

**Note that it happens only for the anonymous users**

What's that?
How could I check which module is redirecting the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check your admin's modules page, for some module related to translation or the locale module.

But some modules can cause this behavior, such as Translation redirect module, part of the Internationalization (i18n) package.

Comment: It was translation redirect. I did not know that it does not require a configuration. Consequently, if you activate that, the redirect automatically happens.
Thanks!